# Auto Copy Cells to New Sheet in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to copy values from sheet "FV" to sheet "AX". I am copying three values from sheet "FV" which reside in cells J7, K7, and L7. My code correctly copies and pastes values J7 and K7, but for some reason L7 isn't getting copied. I am not extremely familiar with VBA, so I am having trouble figuring out the root of the issue in my code.

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim cRng As Range
    Dim dCol As Long
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FV")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AX")
    Set cRng = sht1.Range("J7:L7")
    dCol = sht2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    sht2.Range(Cells(1, dCol).Address, Cells(1, dCol).Address) = cRng.Value
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why the use of address  sht2.Range(Cells(1, dCol).Address, 
    Cells(1, dCol).Address) ?

Comment: It should also be the same size as the range you are setting it equal to.

Comment: sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(1, dCol), sht2.Cells(1, dCol+2))=cRng ?

Comment: @QHarr to future-proof i'd do `sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(1, dCol), sht2.Cells(1, dCol+cRng.columns.count))=cRng` but same answer

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 This worked for me. Thank you both for the above suggestions!

Comment: @jod51, it's actually copying and extra cell...look at my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest lose the .Address as is not required and ensure ranges being set equal to each other are same dimensions e.g

```
sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(1, dCol), sht2.Cells(1, dCol+2))=cRng
```

Fully qualify the cells references inside the range to avoid errors being raised.

Good point from @marucciboy2 re using the column count to ensure width match.

```
sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(1, dCol), sht2.Cells(1, dCol+cRng.columns.count-1))=cRng
```

Comment: Forgot the `-1`... `sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(1, dCol), sht2.Cells(1, dCol+cRng.columns.count-1))` or better yet just `sht2.Cells(1, dCol).Resize(1, 3)`